# Why isn't the iTextSharp PdfWriter.CompressionLevel setter changing the value?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am using iTextSharp (LGPL / MPL) 4.1.6 to take a page range from an existing PDF stream, compress it, and save it into a new file:

```
private static void CreateFile(Stream stream, string filename, int first, int last)
{
    RandomAccessFileOrArray raf = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(stream);
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(raf, null);
    reader.SelectPages(string.Format("{0}-{1}", first, last));
    char version = reader.PdfVersion; // == '4'
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
    {
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs, PdfWriter.VERSION_1_5);
        PdfWriter writer = stamper.Writer;
        writer.SetPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_5);
        writer.CompressionLevel = PdfStream.BEST_COMPRESSION;
        // this will always be true - why?
        if (PdfStream.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION == writer.CompressionLevel)
        {
            var help = "what am I doing wrong?";
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            reader.SetPageContent(i, reader.GetPageContent(i));
        }
        stamper.SetFullCompression();
        stamper.Close();
    }
    reader.Close();
    raf.Close();
}
```

The compression lines are new. But I noticed there was almost no difference in file size before the compression code was added versus after. While stepping through in debug mode, I saw that CompressionLevel is always -1 (default) even though I'm explicitly setting it to 9 (best).

How can I set the compression level to best and get it to stick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compare the [4.1.6 code](https://github.com/itextsharper/iTextSharp-4.1.6/blob/master/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfWriter.cs#L2094) to the [current code](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfWriter.cs#l2217) you'll see that they're performing range-checking on the internal `compressionLevel` variable instead of the property's `value`.

**4.1.6**

```
public int CompressionLevel {
    set {
        if (compressionLevel < PdfStream.NO_COMPRESSION || compressionLevel > PdfStream.BEST_COMPRESSION)
            compressionLevel = PdfStream.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION;
        else
            compressionLevel = value;
    }
    get {
        return compressionLevel;
    }
}
```

**5.4.0**

```
public int CompressionLevel {
    set {
        if (value < PdfStream.NO_COMPRESSION || value > PdfStream.BEST_COMPRESSION)
            compressionLevel = PdfStream.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION;
        else
            compressionLevel = value;
    }
    get {
        return compressionLevel;
    }
}
```

The 4.x series is no longer supported but you can [download the source](https://github.com/itextsharper/iTextSharp-4.1.6) on your own and make that change.

Comment: That did it! The flag definitely changed. However, the resulting split files were more or less the same size as before. I guess the original documents I'm working with are already compressed. D'oh! Thanks.

Comment: I have 5.5.13 (nuget) and can't find the default value of the pdfwriter compression.